# Adding new Exchange (2013) rule very slow

Tags: exchange, outlook, outlook-web-app, exchange-2013, outlook-2013

We have recently rolled out Exchange 2013 + Outlook 2013 across our business, and have just finished migrating users over to this. One of our machine which has 20GB Email (automated emails for logging) takes ages when creating a rule within either Outlook (when you click Add it says `Updating Folders...` and takes over 10 minutes per rule.

Running the same process through OWA takes about 5-10 minutes per rule that we try and create (there are currently around 250 rules already).

My query is:

- Is this due to the amount of email, or number of current rules (or a mixture of both)?
- Is there any way to resolve this, or has anybody else encountered this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having created many rules in my relatively new mailbox all on the same day, I can say that the number of rules on the mailbox is what made my rule creation process slow down. The first five rules I created didn't take that long. Each rule after that point took longer and longer and longer to finish creating. I have about 20 rules and I just stopped creating them and I sort some of my mail manually. Sadly I haven't come up with a workaround or mitigation for the issue yet. Oh yeah my exchange server is actually Office 365, so it might be more of an Outlook issue.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty unusual environment: tons of rules and very large mailbox sizes. Outlook performance deteriorates hard when you have more than 5-10K items in a single folder. The item size is irrelevant; the item count is what matters. You might get better performance from using the New/Get/Set-InboxRule cmdlets.

Comment: This information is correct (although I think Microsoft *claims* to have reduced or fixed the performance issue over 10k items in later version of Outlook), but I have the same experience in an inbox with only 2,600 items, so I'm not sure the item count is related to the rule creation performance issue..